# isset with variable array key count

Tags: php, arrays

The array is multi-dimensional and has a variable number of sub-keys, like

`$arr[$a][$b][$c] = 'X';`

3 in this case. I want to create a function that takes a string like `a.b.c` as argument and checks if the array has that key in it, then unset it: unset($arr[$a][$b][$c]).

if I give it `a.b` then it should unset($arr[$a][$b])

I'd appreciate any help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a recursive approach to your problem:

```
function removeByStr($key, &$arr)
{
    if(!is_array($key))
    {
        $key = explode(".", $key);
    }
    $i = array_shift($key);
    if(count($key) == 0)
    {
        if(!isset($arr[$i]))
        {
            return;
        }
        unset($arr[$i]);
    }
    else if(isset($arr[$i]) && is_array($arr[$i]))
    {
        removeByStr($key, $arr[$i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: If there is `$table[1][2][3]`, with a `1.2.4` key, your function will remove `$table[1][2]` while `$table[1][2][4]` doesn't exist.