# unset inside eval not working

Tags: php, arrays, string

I'm trying to remove an item from an array based on string;

```
  public function delete($path){   

    // a key path given
    if(strpos($path, '.') !== false){

      $parts = explode('.', $path);
      $first_key = array_shift($parts);

      $data = $this->get($path);

      // first key doesn't exist
      if($data === false)
        return false;

      $parts = implode('"]["', $parts);
      if(eval('if(isset($data["'.$parts.'"])){ unset($data["'.$parts.'"]); return true; } return false;'))
        return $this->set($first_key, $data);

    }

    // a single key given
    if(isset($this->data[$path]){
      unset($this->data[$path]);
      return true;
    }

    return false;  
  }
```

And it only works for single keys. Apparently the eval doesn't modify `$data` for some reason.

`delete('test')` works, but `delete('test.child')` doesn't...

Comment: the only thing I can't get is why eval.

Comment: Because there isn't any other reliable solution. But feel free to suggest a different method if you think it can be done...

Comment: From the PHP.net documentation: eval() returns NULL unless return is called in the evaluated code, in which case the value passed to return is returned. Which means you should assign the eval to $data :)

Comment: ah got it. some good samaritan helped you here to access an array. Stackoverflow at it's best.

Comment: nobody help me, it's actually my code :) you're judging this without understanding the problem. I don't like evail either but I have no choice...read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9145392/isset-with-variable-array-key-count)..

Comment: there is always a way. and at first glance there is an accepted answer without eval

Comment: Remove the isset from your eval code. And does the `$this->get()` method return a reference to the `$data` array at all? You are directly accessing the property in the second case, but seemingly use a copy in the first.

Comment: ok i found out the issue. it was get returning the last key, I needed to pass $fist_key to it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why you'd need eval() here. See the following to replace your eval() construct:

```
<?php

function removeFromArray(&$array, $path)
{
    if (!is_array($path)) {
        $path = explode('.', trim($path, '.'));
    }

    $current = &$array;

    while ($path) {
        $key = array_shift($path);

        // isset() would fail on `$array[$key] === null`
        if (!array_key_exists($key, $current)) {
            // abort if the array element does not exist
            return false;
        }

        if (!$path) {
            // reached the last element
            unset($current[$key]);
            return true;
        }

        if (!is_array($current[$key])) {
            // can't go deeper, so abort
            return false;
        }

        // continue with next deeper element
        $current = &$current[$key];
    }

    return false;
}

$data = array(
    'a' => 1,
    'b' => array(
        'c' => 2,
        'd' => 3,
        'e' => array(
            'f' => 4,
        ),
    ),
);

var_dump(
    removeFromArray($data, 'b.e.f'),
    $data,
    removeFromArray($data, 'b.c'),
    $data
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function unset_multiple($arr = [], $keys = [], $limitKeys = 30){
    if($keys && count($keys) <= $limitKeys && is_array($arr) && count($arr) > 0){
        foreach($keys as $key){
      $keys[$key] = null;
        }
        return array_diff_key($arr, $keys);
    } else{
    throw new Exception("Input array is invalid format or number of keys to remove too large");
    }
}
```

Example called:

```
$arr = array("name" => "Vuong", "age" => 20, "address" => "Saigon");
$res = unset_multiple($arr, ["name", "age"]);
//Result: ["address" => "Saigon"]
```

Make sure `$keys` param has all available keys in `$arr` param (only two-dimensional arrays). Need to remember this function is a helper to quickly removing multiple elements of array, not a function returns the absolute accurate results for all cases.